# How to limit access to S3 via interface-type VPC endpoints

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I had been setting up this kind of policy on my IAM users to access Amazon S3:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3.*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    *.*.*.*/32
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In doing so, only access from the IP address specified by `aws:SourceIp` was made possible. However, I now have to go through an interface-type S3 endpoint via Direct Connect to access S3.
Since I cannot specify a private IP for `aws:SourceIp`, I am no longer able to impose connection restrictions based on IP using this method.

Yet, if I were to delete the `aws:SourceIp` condition, this would allow anyone who might somehow get their hands on this IAM user's access key and secret access key to conduct malicious access from anywhere.

So, how would I go about denying access to S3 unless it's through an S3 endpoint or, in other words, unless it's from a network that's connected to my VPC via VPN or Direct Connect, even if they had illegally obtained my access key and secret access key?

Comment: Is `s3.*` actually a valid action or is that a typo in your post?

Comment: Note that you can supply VPC endpoint conditions in S3 bucket policies. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies-vpc-endpoint.html).

Comment: Sorry. It was actually `s3:*`.

Comment: I omitted one condition: some IAM users access S3 via AWS Management Console. For them, we will continue to restrict access based on IP address. Therefore, bucket policy restrictions are not suitable.
Is there any way to control this with an IAM policy?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [data perimeter](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/data-perimeters-on-aws/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a VPC Endpoint to access S3, then you're correct: you cannot use `aws:SourceIp`.  However, you can instead use [`aws:VpcSourceIp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-vpcsourceip).  Since private IP addresses are not unique (or more accurately, are even less unique than public ones), you should combine your `aws:VpcSourceIp` condition with an [`aws:SourceVpc`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourcevpc) condition to ensure that you allow only the correct addresses from the correct VPC.

Your permission policy will look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "IpAddress": {
                "aws:VpcSourceIp": [
                    *.*.*.*/32
                ]
            },
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-12345678"
            }
        }
    }
}
```